# Can I use MVC 5 remote validation to check for duplicate values, but exclude the item being edited?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have set up some validation for my form to check if the serial number that is entered already exists.  This works perfectly for creating a **new** item, but when **editing** an item and submitting, it doesn't recognize that the edited item has the serial number that is causing the issue.  Is it possible to get the IsSerialAvailable action to recognize that the user is editing the item, and ignore that value?

**Annotations:**

```
[Display(Name = "Serial #")]
[Remote("IsSerialAvailable", "Item", ErrorMessage = "Serial # already exists.")]
public string Serial { get; set; }
```

**Controller code:**

```
public ActionResult IsSerialAvailable(string Serial)
    {
        using (db)
        {
            try
            {
                var serial = db.Items.Single(i => i.Serial == Serial);
                return Json(false, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: if the object has a primary key you can edit the method to `IsSerialAvailable(string Serial, int id)` and then edit your linq `var serial = db.Items.Single(i => i.Serial == Serial && i.id != id);`. I would also add that you can call SingleorDefault() which will return null if it doesn't exits. Which saves you throwing that exception. `return serial == null;`

Comment: @Jonathan.Hickey I use a generated identity for the ID field that gets inserted after the form is posted, so adding a hidden ID field unfortunately wouldn't work on the create page.

Comment: you can make it take a nullabe int. If the Id  is null then do as your doing for the create if the Id hasvalue then do the second query as above. I'll write the solution when I get home.

Comment: OK, thanks.  If you make it an answer, I'll mark it.

Comment: I just tried passing the ID from the edit page, and it doesn't seem to be working.  Are you maybe not able to pass multiple form values using remote validation?  I see the hidden value when looking at HTML using the browser inspector tools, but it always comes up as null from the edit page.

Comment: Hi @sjohn285, any chance you had time to try the answer below.  I have tested it locally and can confirm the solution does work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you will need 2 view models. One for create and one for edit. By passing the item id we know that it is an edit, and if it is not past we know it is a create.

```
public class CreateItemViewModel
{
    [Remote("IsSerialAvailable", "Value")]
    public string Serial { get; set; }
}

public class EditItemViewModel
{
    [Remote("IsSerialAvailable", "Value", AdditionalFields = "ItemId")]
    public string Serial { get; set; }

    public int ItemId { get; set; }
}

    public ActionResult IsSerialAvailable(string serial, int? itemId = null)
    {
        List<int> t = new List<int>();

        Item item;

        if (itemId.HasValue)
        {
            item = db.Items.SingleOrDefault(i => i.Serial == Serial && i.Id != itemId.Value);

        }
        else
        {
            item = db.Items.SingleOrDefault(i => i.Serial == Serial);
        }

        if (item != null)
        {
            return Json(false, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the action name to see if the request came's from create or edit.

```
public ActionResult IsSerialAvailable(string Serial)
    {
        using (db)
        {
            try
            {
                var actionName = HttpContext.Request.UrlReferrer.Segments[2];
                var serial = db.Items.Single(i => i.Serial == Serial);
                return Json(false, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
    }
```

But what i would recomend is a custom validation

http://dotnetmentors.com/mvc/how-to-do-custom-validation-using-validationattribute-of-aspnet-mvc.aspx

Comment: What can I do with the action name that would help?